# I want to use multi-dropdown

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to use multi-dropdown. But It occurs 'Index out of range' error

```
var drop: Array<DropDown?> = []
var dropDataSource: Array<String> = []
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

I declared like this.

```
func setDropDown() {

    for i in 0...15 {
        drop[i] = DropDown()
        drop[i]?.anchorView = button
        drop[i]?.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y:(dropDown?.anchorView?.plainView.bounds.height)!)
        switchDropData(dataCount: i)
        drop[i]?.dataSource = dropDataSource
        buttons[i].addTarget(self, action: #selector(dropBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
        drop[i]?.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
            self.buttons[i].setTitle(item, for: .normal)
        }

    }

}

@objc func dropBtn(dataCount: Int) {
    drop[dataCount]?.show()
}
```

and make 15 dropdowns.

but `drop[I] = DropDown()` results in error.

I know what does 'Index out of range error' mean.

But I don't know why this code has error.

Is there anything, I'm missing in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new DropDown() and then append it to the drop array

```
func setDropDown() {

 for i in 0...15 {
    var newDrop = DropDown()
    newDrop.anchorView = button
    newDrop.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y:(dropDown.anchorView?.plainView.bounds.height)!)
    switchDropData(dataCount: i)
    newDrop.dataSource = dropDataSource
    buttons[i].addTarget(self, action: #selector(dropBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
    newDrop.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
        self.buttons[i].setTitle(item, for: .normal)
    }
    drop.append(newDrop)
 }

}
```

---

Comment: `newDrop` wouldn't be an optional, I'm assuming.

Comment: Also, your solution will still cause the same error, just on a different line :)

Comment: I solve my problem similar with you. But your solution causes AppDelegate error. I don't know what is problem. 'dropDown' should be changed to 'newDrop' at 6 line in your answer.

Comment: @youngtaek you shouldn't accept solutions that cause more errors :)

Answer (score 1):

`Index out of range` means that you're trying to access an element in an array that doesn't exist, because the index is outside the range of the array (from first to last).

It looks like your array is not populated.
You should change the following to prevent the error:

```
for i in 0...15 {
```

...to:

```
for d in drop {
```

This will effectively loop through all elements in the array. If there are 0 elements in the array, the loop won't go off at all, so that you won't get an `index out of bounds` error.

---

If you want to *create* dropdowns, instead of not accessssing them, you need to initialize a new variable and then append the new dropdown to the array:

```
for _ in 0...15 {
    var dropdown = DropDown()
    drop.append(dropdown)
    dropdown.anchorView = button
    // ...
}
```